# The same method in derived classes but with different parameters

Tags: c++, oop, vector

I don't know how to describe my issue. I'd like to find out if it is possible to write a function in base class which would be the same for derived classes but passing different parameters. Maybe it would be easier to see in my code than the describe it:

```
class Employee
{
public:
    std::string name, profession;
    std::string current_task = "NONE";
    int id, age;

    // checks if the input by user a new task belongs to duties list
    // for the class; if it does then it changes the current task 
    std::string AssignNewTask(std::vector<std::string> v, std::string input_string)
    {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
        {
            if (input_string == v[i])
            {
                return input_string;
            }
        }

        return "NONE";
    }
};

class HR : public Employee
{
private:
    static std::vector<std::string> tasks; //list of duties for HR employees

public:
    HR::HR()
    {
        Employee::profession = "HR Specialist";
    }
    //the same function as above but passing tasks (std::vector with duties)
    std::string AssignNewTask(tasks, std::string input_string) 
};

std::vector<std::string> HR::tasks = { "something" };

int main()
{
    HR obj;
    // 'something1' does not belong to duties list so still "NONE"
    obj.AssignNewTask("something1"); 
    // 'something' belongs so current_task has been changed
    obj.AssignNewTask("something");
}
```

I know that the code does not work. I just wanted to show what I exactly mean.

Comment: what exactly does not work in this code?

Comment: Your code can't be compiled because you have no overload for `AssignNewTask` which takes one argument.

Comment: it is just a part of my code because I don't really know how to write it. The code above does not work because `obj.AssignNewTask("something1")` needs two arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand the objective correctly;

- We want to have a base class that provides a `AssignNewTask` function
- that will only assign the task if it is contained in the task list of the derived class.

The following adapted version of the program does that. `AssignNewTask` is in the base, but during construction it will get a reference to the task list of the derived class.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class Employee {
public:
    Employee(std::vector<std::string>& tasks) : tasks{tasks} {}; // we need a constructor here to pass the reference to the tasks
    std::string name,profession;
    std::string current_task = "NONE";
    int id,age;

    std::vector<std::string>& tasks; // tasks now refers to the derived list of tasks

    // checks if the input by user a new task belongs to duties list for the class; if it does then it changes the current task 
    virtual void AssignNewTask(std::string input_string)
    {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < tasks.size(); i++) {
            if (input_string == tasks[i]) {
                current_task = input_string;
            }
        }
    }
};

class HR : public Employee {
public:
    HR::HR()
        : Employee(tasks) // We now pass the list of tasks by reference
    {
        Employee::profession = "HR Specialist";
    }

    //AssignNewTask not required here as it has already been inherited

private:
    static std::vector<std::string> tasks; //list of duties for HR employees

};


std::vector<std::string> HR::tasks ={"something"};

int main()
{
    HR obj;

    obj.AssignNewTask("something1"); // 'something1' does not belong to duties list so still "NONE"
    obj.AssignNewTask("something"); // 'something' belongs so current_task has been changed
}
```

You might also prefer a [range based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) rather than the one we currently have:

```
for (const auto& task : tasks) {
    if (input_string == task) {
        current_task = input_string;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is exactly what I meant. I'd like to make sure if I understand it properly: 1. have you created an empty `std::vector<std::string> tasks` so the compiler won't return the error? 2. why have you written `std::vector<std::string> &tasks` instead `std::vector<std::string> tasks`? 3. what does the line `Employee(std::vector<std::string>& tasks) : tasks{tasks} {};` mean? 4. why `HR` constuctor passing `tasks`?

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to find out if it is possible to write a function in base
>   class which would be the same for derived classes but passing
>   different parameters

It is possible, but it is going to hide the base function in the context if you try to achieve the polymorphism by using the base pointer assigned with derived class object.

Comment: Could you tell me more about it? I see that I should place the method into `protected`, shouldn't I? But what next? I just don't understand the point.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be many problems with your code.  First off, if you want to have a base class override your parent class function, the parent has to declare the function as `virtual`.  Next, it seems like the methods actually do take the same parameters, you are just confusing the HR's instance of a vector with the actual type of the vector.  How about you typedef the vector of strings for both classes:

```
// new type now named StringVector
typedef std::vector<std::string> StringVector;

class Employee
{
public:
    std::string name, profession;
    std::string current_task = "NONE";
    int id, age;

    // checks if the input by user a new task belongs to duties list for the class; if it does then it changes the current task 
    virtual std::string AssignNewTask(StringVector v, std::string input_string)
    {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
        {
            if (input_string == v[i])
            {
                return input_string;
            }
        }

        return "NONE";
    }
};

class HR : public Employee
{
private:
    static StringVector tasks; //list of duties for HR employees

public:
    HR::HR()
    {
        Employee::profession = "HR Specialist";
    }

    std::string AssignNewTask(StringVector tasks, std::string input_string)
    {
        // do something
    }

};

std::vector<std::string> HR::tasks = { "something" };

int main()
{
    HR obj;

    obj.AssignNewTask("something1"); // 'something1' does not belong to duties list so still "NONE"
    obj.AssignNewTask("something"); // 'something' belongs so current_task has been changed
}
```

I hope this answers your question for you.

Comment: not completely. But as you noticed there are many problems. I've forgotten about declare function as `virtual`. @flatmouse guessed what I meant.

Comment: @mathsicist ah, I had a feeling that I was missing the actual question.  Glad you got your answer anyway.